# TypeScript class method overloads not behaving the same as function overloads

Tags: typescript, class, generics, overloading

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, but my search has not turned up anything that quite fits the issue I'm having.

Firstly, the desired behavior is to have a class method with two params, the second optional, where the second param's type is dependent on the first param's type. If the first param is type A, the second param should always be required and should be of type X, if the first param is type B, the second param should be omitted.

I've achieved something quite like this with function overloading:

```
// types
enum MessageType { FOO, BAR, BAZ }

type MessagePayload<T extends MessageType> = T extends MessageType.FOO 
    ? string
    : T extends MessageType.BAR
    ? number
    : never;

// overloads
function sendMessage<T extends MessageType.BAZ>(action: T): void

function sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload: MessagePayload<T>): void

// implementation
function sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload?: MessagePayload<T>) {
  // do something
}

// tests
sendMessage(MessageType.FOO, "10") // no error - as expected
sendMessage(MessageType.FOO, 10)   // error - as expected, payload is not string
sendMessage(MessageType.FOO)       // error - as expected, payload must be string
sendMessage(MessageType.BAZ);      // no error - as expected - since MessageType is BAZ
```

However, the same exact constructs, when applied to a class method, do not produce the same results. This snippet is a continuation of the first and uses the same types:

```
// interface
interface ISomeClient {
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType.BAZ>(action: T): void

  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload: MessagePayload<T>): void
}

// implementation
class SomeClient implements ISomeClient {
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload?: MessagePayload<T>) {
    // do something
  }
}

// tests
const client = new SomeClient();

client.sendMessage(MessageType.FOO, "10"); // no error - as expected
client.sendMessage(MessageType.FOO, 10);   // error, payload is not string
client.sendMessage(MessageType.FOO)        // no error??? different behavior than function example
client.sendMessage(MessageType.BAZ);       // this part works fine
```

Here is a more complete example on the [TS Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/PQKgBAvF07fwxTmIFBnAFQJ4AcCmAzuuCmeRZbCcKqvgHYCuAtmALJGECGA5vjgJgA3ujAAxAPKSANGIBCAQQBKcsGCUAtNWACKizDv3bUAXzoAXPPjABVQvgBOkEWIbcW+AFxhCFxwCWDLwA3GIBACY+zCwARk5h5qhWQpyEPPwACtzYADYA9twRADyYYPgAHhaMEYQcXHwC1gB8LmWV1Qy19emNgvgAdFKSYGLqAPy+-kG8Y2A+7VU1dWkZTQQDSspzkzHxjnML5UtdKw38-ZuKmjt2Dgfq6tH4AG4JdKigkFQ-v38kYAA6vlHABrGYSJgMADGFgC+QYAL+yJRKBodAAZlDYfCGL4aqtGqVjp1uoSLtYBvoygAfHprS7GZoACm4OIRCwAlD4XvlIpjsXCEfiuuT8MSOst6X0Wqz2QwFjIwLgcgUij4xdk8oUSphmtywLz+agsTChXiHKLzuLFqSzr0KQQWXM2ebFXMVdqiuMNdatWrdfrXI9HsBgGAIvlfPlPBYABYzMx0MNgap+YiWiJi5liy7DJUAIj8gWCBc5qEz2dzlOGnLAKacjhBYAAtGBuHVKgRYfgIhWCdac9bGQZOSF6+GGFHG822x3jt3qn3PqRUWv11AAQA5fIWIEg8HBMAAYVyHeIGG+G+v-wwtFQQWqjgxbJsAEkAMox-CngKMPeiOolbWhKJxksOlLUmAdLVhsTJym6YCYAaRrLkBA4OjaJJSrB+Asq6uKKsqqo6r6mH+jqpT6jyfJ9kk0JnukYBfp4v7-mAAQsLguT4J4DAWHUn7fmx-HBiKWYgbaOEQU6CGEUhSqegGPrSlkJFFFRdaAaG4aRtGsYJsEYjmPRCJ+GADF-qJEBgAw+AAO7McJuRWRYzJjsm4ZpgJqCWf+AzAZhQ6YXm0iFsWMxlr5Ln+YFazBQyNbSHWKZTuUjhNo44zZdFrkBRh8W4VSo5hHQQA).

So, I guess this is a two-parter:

1. why is this not working for the class example?
2. is there some better way to achieve this that will work for both classes and functions and that doesn't require maintaining an overload to capture the types that don't require a payload? I've used an enum and a conditional type here to constrain the second param to match what's expected given the first param. I've played around with [another way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFMGcBQU6gKr1gJ1AXlAN6KigB2AhgLawBco84WAlqQOYDciAvoogMYB7Ug1ABZBPHKtYAFRiwS+IiQBiAeTV0ARFoA0xUACEAggCU6ABn0kTALToBXUgBNYAMxaxn10AEVjMnQEXKDk8OiYWNy8IKACAG7YADYC5M5Ibk584ExC9LAu4vCS0gA8MqCwAB7gBekQ8gJuYhJSsvIAfAAU5Nm5pNp2WgCUdPECTM68maR9eZiFrWUV1bUu4SiwTS3FbXJwuqAA0pU1deEA1rCQ2zLdvTlCdEeH0OSQKWl0MgDaRwC6o1A40mMTATEo0CSsGopHA5EepEQMzmpHyi12y1Oa3qm22RRK7QOx2x51AVxuzTuPVRz1e70+zgA-N8-oDCAZYs4BPQBNRwAALFisaKIWK1BhIBbOAltLpadRqPSgLQARgsI1AsVIPOwWAEOAAtKFwtU4NkvIhpbLpPLFcr1cMSFqwHqDaBjWFTubat5QG8PqlnKAmOEdeB6IxhVa6jbYHaNJrnc7Ym6jSbvbALX6A4zQJQHCIAEYKBjMNgxjGE+VDYbsZMkbW6rD69Nes1Z30e+gsPgKOP7BShozGWxgkNw7BuXqwRAsWpYad90AASQAynzYABhJJMAoR5TomVLWDlUnrBpwfEnwf3Wkq2tjCZTEjWk9n1ZkvHNAfyQ4nT8LwpW470ROl-QZINWQBIEQSmHgxXBSFoVheFEX4JIwnCDdqB3Pc4RDZCYX3cJ103PD9w5V9Y3fFYzgvb8dkJQd-3PepgKpUD+nA3MgxZUBfhgqiXVAbleX5IUKxIHgEPFBBwCQQRhAjPhd0o-BSFgAB3UAcO3NS4S6OteFU-DwAAOjfTF4wVRNDjVDUnSbSoW3dT1TSqH1LVM-dLJo6yEyVQ5HRTV1XLbDyvJzSC0hDMMBAjMtox8uE-KrOVbKVJ0GxEnUXNbABCJkmQwsy0uPAKtFresG2ctNu3bTzOy8bt4F7fsb3kOKR1sIA) involving an key to type map but it seems hacky, still requires overloads, and suffers from this same issue for classes and functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### 1. why is this not working for the class example?

I think the issue is that the signature in the `class` isn't being treated as just an implementation signature like the third standalone function signature is, because the overloads are declared separately. So the `class` is *augmenting* those, adding a third public signature, in contrast to the function overloads where the third signature is not public, it's just the [implementation signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature).

You can fix it by not putting the overloads (just) in the interface declaration. Either don't use an interface:

```typescript
class SomeClient {
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType.QAT | MessageType.QAZ>(action: T): void;
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload: MessagePayload<T>): void;
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload?: MessagePayload<T>) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/PQKgBAvF07fwxTmIFBnAFQJ4AcCmAzuuCmeRZbCcKqvgHYCuAtmALJGECGA5vjgJgA3ujAAxAPKSANGIBCAQQBKcsGCUAtNWACKizDv3bUAXzoAXPPjABVQvgBOkEWIbcW+AFxhCFxwCWDLwA3GIBACY+zCwARk5h5qhWQpyEPPwACtzYADYA9twRADyYYPgAHhaMEYQcXHwC1gB8LmWV1Qy19emNgvgAdFKSYGLqAPy+-kG8Y2A+7VU1dWkZTQQDSspzkzHxjnML5UtdKw38-ZuKmjt2Dgfq6tH4AG4JdKigkFQ-v38kYAA6vlHABrGYSJgMADGFgC+QYAL+yJRKBodAAZlDYfCGL4aqtGqVjp1uoSLtYBvoygAfHprS7GZoACm4OIRCwAlD4XvlIpjsXCEfiuuT8MSOst6X0Wqz2QwFjIwLgcgUij4xdk8oUSphmtywLz+agsTChXiHKLzuLFqSzr0KQQWXM2ebFXMVdqiuMNdatWrdfrXI9HsBgGAIvlfPlPBYABYzMx0MNgap+YiWiJi5liy7DJUAIj8gWCBc5qEz2dzlOGnLAKacjhBYAAtGBuHVKgRYfgIhWCdac9bGQZOSF6+GGFHG822x3jt3qn3PqRUWv11AAcyAHL5ADudeBYIhAGFch3iBhvhub-8MLRUNDz+kwABlGP4M8BRgWYMirPWhKJxksOlLUmAdLVhsTJym6YCYAaRoRGE6iVoBtpSlB+Asq6uKKsqqo6r6Dr4P6OqlPqPJ8shYhoSRQF2tKjrYbBeHwUqnoBj6TGkYRRQUXWoghimkbRrGCbBGI5hJNCCJ+GAT7fgwv4QGADD4Hub4fl+P7MmOybhmmFjEIpP4DHRaxDiRebSIWxYzGWYSmcp5kDiRVkMjW0hjhOYAAKKOE2zjzhERABI4vaPrkSkWK5VruVhVKjmEQA)

...or do use an interface, but also repeat the overloads in the `class` construct so TypeScript knows that the third one is an implementation signature:

```typescript
interface ISomeClient {
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType.QAT | MessageType.QAZ>(action: T): void
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload: MessagePayload<T>): void
}

class SomeClient implements ISomeClient {
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType.QAT | MessageType.QAZ>(action: T): void
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload: MessagePayload<T>): void
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(action: T, payload?: MessagePayload<T>) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/PQKgBAvF07fwxTmIFBnAFQJ4AcCmAzuuCmeRZbCcKqvgHYCuAtmALJGECGA5vjgJgA3ujAAxAPKSANGIBCAQQBKcsGCUAtNWACKizDv3bUAXzoAXPPjABVQvgBOkEWIbcW+AFxhCFxwCWDLwA3GIBACY+zCwARk5h5qhWQpyEPPwACtzYADYA9twRADyYYPgAHhaMEYQcXHwC1gB8LmWV1Qy19emNgvgAdFKSYGLqAPy+-kG8Y2A+7VU1dWkZTQQDSspzkzHxjnML5UtdKw38-ZuKmjt2Dgfq6tH4AG4JdKigkFQ-v38kYAA6vlHABrGYSJgMADGFgC+QYAL+yJRKBodAAZlDYfCGL4aqtGqVjp1uoSLtYBvoygAfHprS7GZoACm4OIRCwAlD4XvlIpjsXCEfiuuT8MSOst6X0Wqz2QwFjIwLgcgUij4xdk8oUSphmtywLz+agsTChXiHKLzuLFqSzr0KQQWXM2ebFXMVdqiuMNdatWrdfrXI9HsBgGAIvlfPlPBYABYzMx0MNgap+YiWiJi5liy7DJUAIj8gWCBc5qEz2dzlOGnLAKacjhBYAAtGBuHVKgRYfgIhWCdac9bGQZOSF6+GGFHG822x3jt3qn3PqRUWv11AAcyAHL5ADudeBYIhAGFch3iBhvhub-8MLRUEFqo4MWybABJADKMfwZ4CjAsYMRSza0JROMlh0pakwDpasNiZOU3TATADSNPt1ErUDbSlOD8BZV1cUVZVVR1X0HXwf0dVKfUeT5Pskmhc90jAb9PD-ACwACFhcFyfBPAYCw6i-H92IEoDMPIsC7WlR1Bmg2DIPg658PlLlaP5DCB0k7DThk9Y8MQwjkKVT0AzItZKKKajULosQJLWKScMUgyCI5YziK9CIfT0yzAzrUQQxTSNo1jBNgjEcwGIRPwwEY-8xIgMAGHwPcWJE3J4osZkx2TcM00E1A4oAgZ7MaIdyLzaRC2LGYyzCIqBJKrS1nKhka2kMcJzAABRRwm2cecIiIAJHF7QqMuK0r+FamUlJQsIgA)

That's repetitive, but I'm not sure there's a way around it other than assigning to `SomeClient.prototype` after-the-fact.

> ### 2. is there some better way to achieve this...

I tend to like function overloads for this, but it's true that they don't work for everything and if you have lots of these, it'll get unwieldy fast.

I should note that I'm still just at the journeyman level with TypeScript so there may be other options, but I can think of two alternatives:

1. Using a rest argument with a varying tuple type
2. Using a discriminated union so there's always only one parameter

In places I've found function overloads to be too cumbersome, I've tended toward discriminated unions, but the tuple idea was kind of cute so I thought I'd include it.

#### Rest + Tuple

Instead of `MessagePayload<T>`, you have `MessageParams<T>` defining a tuple based on `T`:

```typescript
type MessageParams<T extends MessageType> = T extends MessageType.FOO 
    ? [T, string]
    : T extends MessageType.BAR
    ? [T, number]
    : T extends MessageType.BAZ
    ? [T, User]
    : [T];
```

(If you need `MessagePayload<T>` for other reasons, you can derive it from the above: `type MessagePayload2<T extends MessageType> = MessageParams<T>[1];`.)

Then the method uses that as the type of a rest parameter:

```typescript
class SomeClient {
  sendMessage<T extends MessageType>(...args: MessageParams<T>) {
    const action = args[0];
    // do something
  }
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/PQKgBAvF07fwxTmIFBnAFQJ4AcCmAzuuCmeRZbCcKqvgHYCuAtmALJGECGA5vjgJgA3ujAAxAPKSANGIBCAQQBKcsGCUAtNWACKizDv3bUAXzoAXPPjABVQvgBOkEWIbcW+AFxhCFxwCWDLwA3GIBACY+zCwARk5h5qhWQpyEPPwACtzYADYA9twRADyYYPgAHhaMEYQcXHwC1gB8LmWV1Qy19emNgvgAdFKSYGLqAPy+-kG8Y2A+7VU1dWkZTQQDSspzkzHxjnML5UtdKw38-ZuKmjt2Dgfq6tH4AG4JdKigkFQ-v38kYAA6vlHABrGYSJgMADGFgC+QYAL+yJRKBodAAZlDYfCGL4aqtGqVjp1uoSLtYBvoygAfHprS7GZoACm4OIRCwAlD4XvlIpjsXCEfiuuT8MSOst6X0Wqz2QwFjIwLgcgUij4xdk8oUSphmtywLz+agsTChXiHKLzuLFqSzr0KQQWXM2ebFXMVdqiuMNdatWrdfrXI9HsBgGAIvlfPlPBYABYzMx0MNgap+YiWiJi5liy7DJUAIj8gWCBc5qEz2dzlOGnLAKacjhBYAAtGBuHVKgRYfgIhWCdac9bGQZOSF6+GGFHG822x3jt3qn3PqRUWv11AAcyAHL5ADudeBYIhAGFch3iBhvhub-8MLQUjZNdxHB5CBKTmThy02iSpdWNmGUYQ0mABtQwphLXgAF1DjAW1-2-DYtlucClT2JxYJDI5JVOaVHUGLRUIg+xMLg8DoLCT5wwATXyJgwGhbg8QiJwAjefD8H9HUwAxJs2ACCwwACDEwGweiwFyAJQW8ZJrE47iigAJg-O1OP6VoIAUl831KZpQIARkouhoXPdIwAAZRjfAzwCRghNEdRK2tVTEIddZ8BZAZvJfXhCF9dzslfFh3z1OtHMeaEET8dt5RcXzCFAgAGYyQxTSNo1jBNgjEcwkiihgYtMuyGCErSGHwPdLOs2z7OZMdk3DNMLGIYr7IGZz3KHdy82kQtixmMswja0qOoHLqAMGWtxxTABRRwm2cedWMIAJHF7VARosMarQmpDBmpBqgA)

The developer experience is very much like overloads, though.

#### Discriminated Union

This last option is a bigger change: You don't have separate parameters at all, just a single object type that's a discriminated union:

```typescript
type FOOMessage = {action: MessageType.FOO; payload: string;};
type BARMessage = {action: MessageType.BAR; payload: number;};
type BAZMessage = {action: MessageType.BAZ; payload: User;};
type OtherMessage = {action: Exclude<MessageType, MessageType.FOO | MessageType.BAR | MessageType.BAZ>;};
// `OtherMessage` is the catch-all for all message types other than the
// ones with their own interface, note the use of `Exclude`

type Message = FOOMessage | BARMessage | BAZMessage | OtherMessage;

// ...

class SomeClient {
  sendMessage(message: Message) {
    const action = message.action;
    // do something
  }
}
```

The calls to it change to passing an object:

```typescript
// tests
client.sendMessage({action: MessageType.FOO, payload: "string"});
client.sendMessage({action: MessageType.FOO}); // Error as desired
client.sendMessage({action: MessageType.QAT});
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/PQKgBAvF07fwxTmIFBnAFQJ4AcCmAzuuCmeRZbCcKqvgHYCuAtmALJGECGA5vjgJgA3ujAAxAPKSANGIBCAQQBKcsGCUAtNWACKizDv3bUAXzoAXPPjABVQvgBOkEWIbcW+AFxhCFxwCWDLwA3GIBACY+zCwARk5h5qhWQpyEPPwACtzYADYA9twRADyYYPgAHhaMEYQcXHwC1gB8LmWV1Qy19emNgvgAdFKSYGLqAPy+-kG8Y2A+7VU1dWkZTQQDSspzkzHxjnML5UtdKw38-ZuKmjt2Dgfq6tH4AG4JdKigkFQ-v38kYAA6vlHABrGYSJgMADGFgC+QYAL+yJRKBodAAZlDYfCGL4aqtGqVjp1uoSLtYBvoygAfHprS7GZoACm4OIRCwAlD4XvlIpjsXCEfiuuT8MSOst6X0Wqz2QwFjIwLgcgUij4xdk8oUSphmtywLz+agsTChXiHKLzuLFqSzr0KQQWXM2ebFXMVdqiuMNdatWrdfrXI9HsBgGAIvlfPlPBYABYzMx0MNgap+YiWiJi5liy7DJUAIj8gWCBc5qEz2dzlOGnLAKacjhBYAAtGBuHVKgRYfgIhWCdac9bGQZOSF6+GGFHG822x3jt3qn3PqRUWv11AAcyAHL5ADudeBYIhAGFch3iBhvhub-8MLRktYJNIxS5hK7cb6HetBsNx56Ax8YsZhCUwwhSGwtlfCARA-DlpUdQYtn-VUdWiVh9lA8Cny0aDYPlL8GUpLQUK9KI7gSMDHyESR4ycPD3wIsAAFEKmhXImAicVqwIJUeN-aQwDpfirmUISEJ-K5NGaLDPnDAADWi43o615LAAI6josBoW4CxoTjFtuFyXIwAxZsjJMzxv1Taw6nyOjnHjbg8TouSwARIgwD3AJ41TZSAmcfc8SCapHAxNl8CVKdqj8mwmAcdyMTAeTWPYzj8Hkywnzw4ZXzpKDrXE3DCrpJSVO-MJUHYi8wAAZRjfAzwCRgLGDEUs0HKy1kIxo61EENoQRPx23lFwusaAY4IYMIQxTSNo1jBNgjEcwkkGhhhvY5qGFamCGHwPc6oapqWuZMdk3DNMLGILaWoGStB0Yt0JLzaQlQAtCwCLaZS1Mc7bp2+6B2-Zkns-F6a2kP7xxTZjHCbZx5y4wgAt7Krcm2iwgatEGwfgkTqWh1AgA)

Comment: Apologies for the post-and-run (I'm not a fan of doing that!) but I've been called away. I will come back later to respond to anything that comes up in the comments. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: @TJCrowder No worries, I actually did a post-and-run myself as I posted this right before running out for a few hours :-). Taking a look at your answer now

Comment: @TJCrowder ahhh... I see. Very interesting, and a bit unexpected, and hard to get from the docs on function overloads, and the classes documentation doesn't deal specifically with method overloads as far as I can tell. However, I think I understand this now and the first solution (to just add the overloads directly to the class method [which I didn't even realize you could do]) makes the most sense and seems like the better solution. This is exactly the fix I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @TJCrowder For part 2 of the question, do you have any better suggestions on how to achieve this in the first place? i.e. require an optional param in some cases, but not in all. This could get verbose if there are many message types with different types of payloads, and you'd also have to continue to maintain the overload for every message type that does not require a payload as well. Perhaps this is as good as it gets, but open to other approaches (though this does work like a charm in my current setup).

Comment: @no_stack_dub_sack - Sorry, I did just skip right over part 2, didn't I? I've added to the end of the answer. I can think of two alternatives. Hope this helps!

Comment: @TJCrowder Hmm... the second option with the union types seems a bit too verbose and maintenance heavy in a different way and would def prefer the overload approach over this. The first option, however, seems like the least maintenance of all, since the only thing that needs to be updated when a new message type is added is `MessageParams<T>`. That said, the intellisense that VS Code provides with this approach isn't as nice, since you just get `arg0` and `arg1` instead of named args. This might be an ok tradeoff, especially since the call signature doesn't change at all with this approach.

Comment: @TJCrowder I've also found a way to slightly improve the original overload solution. Basically, you maintain one extra type, which is a whitelist (union) of message types that don't require payloads. This way, you only ever need to have two overloads, the overload syntax will remain succinct, and if a developer does not update one of the two types, the code will not compile. It's a bit more effort than the tuple approach, but at least you never have to touch the overload, and you still get good intellisense at the call site: https://shorturl.at/ahtyM